# Handling null when binding to an Image in XAML

Tags: wpf, binding

I have an Image element in XAML. I bind the Source property to a string property in my ViewModel. However, sometimes the value is null and then I get errors in the debug window.

I read here: [ImageSourceConverter error for Source=null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399601/wpf-imagesourceconverter-error-for-source-null) that I could make a converter to return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue if the value is null.

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to do it directly in XAML? Perhaps by using a FallbackValue?
I have tried some variants but with no luck.

This is my Image element in XAML:

```
<Image Name="img" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentImageSource}" Stretch="None" />
```

And CurrentImageSource is just a string property on the DataContext.

The error message is:
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 :

> Cannot convert '' from type '' to type
>   'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'sv-SE' culture with default
>   conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding.
>   NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException:
>   ImageSourceConverter cannot convert from (null).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I used x:Null with TargetNullValue, that way you get an easy blank image...

```
<Image Source="{Binding LogoPath, TargetNullValue={x:Null}}" />
```

That way you don't need to mess around with Triggers or BitmapImages as static resources.

Answer (score 22):

You can [check for a null reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743649.aspx) using a data trigger:

```xml
<Image Name="img" Stretch="None" >
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding CurrentImageSource}" /> 
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentImageSource}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/ImageNullRef;component/errorImage.png" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Whilst it is not possible to test directly whether two values differ, you can see whether a value is greater or smaller, etc. using [this approach Mike Hillberg blogged about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/09/30/comparabledatatrigger.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for some simpler syntax (lika setting a FallbackValue) but I guess it's not possible.

Answer (score 19):

I haven't tested it, but I think this is what TargetNullValue is for:

```
<Image Name="img" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentImageSource, TargetNullValue=/ImageNullRef;component/errorImage.png}" Stretch="None" />
```

Comment: Nice one. Cut and pasting did not quite work. I needed to create a image resource (`<BitmapImage x:Key='defaultImage' UriSource='/ImageNullRef;component/errorImage.png' />`) and then reference it like so `<Image Name="img" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentImageSource, TargetNullValue={StaticResource defaultImage}}" Stretch="None" />`. Valid answer and I learned something -> +1

Comment: Very nice. I like this. +1

Answer (score 0):

I just check the answer of Sascha Hennig. It runs well on my side. I just have a little modification on my side (remove `/ImageNullRef;` in image resource)
`<BitmapImage x:Key='defaultImage' UriSource='component/errorImage.png' />`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the source is a `Uri`, I had this problem too when the `Image` control is about to be unloaded. For some reason the Image's `Source` was being set to null by the Presentation framework. The `ImageSourceConverter` didn't know how to convert a null to a concrete ImageSource instance (ImageSource is abstract). That's why using `TargetNulValue={x:Null}` in the binding works - if `Source` is `null` it doesn't try to convert to an `ImageSource`.

Another option, instead of setting the `Source` property on the `Image`, use an explicit `BitmapImageSource` and set its `UriSource`.

```
<Image Name="img" Stretch="None">
  <Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=CurrentImageSource}"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```