# Cannot show quickly list of images in WPF ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have ItemsControl (listbox) with some custom complex data templates. And its take few seconds to show window with this listbox!

My listbox datatemplate contains image:

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform"
       x:Name="image"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
       Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
       Width="Auto"
       Grid.Column="0"
       MinWidth="20"
       MinHeight="20"
       d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox"
       Margin="1,0,1,1" />
```

Almost all ImagePaths is null. I noticed that this null generates exception but wpf engine hides it! I think this is the source of problem. Is it possible to disable image loading when i know that image path is null!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this `DataTrigger` to your `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ImagePath}" Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: And what this will do? This will set null in case if value null?

Comment: @Evgeny have you tried it? This will prevent the default `TypeConverter` from throwing an exception, which is what is actually causing your delay.

Comment: Or you could combine the two answers and use `Source={Binding ImagePath, FallbackValue={x:Null}}` and get the same result.

Comment: Looks like I spoke to soon.  Still throws when you do that, so don't use my idea.

Comment: But what if i will bind setter Value={Binding ImagePath} if imagepath==null is false?

Comment: @Evgeny I don't understand your question. Have you tried my example?

Comment: @HighCore i am testing it.

Comment: @HighCore Just was tested. Same problem. Each image generates exception:

Comment: ImageSourceConverter cannot convert from System.String.   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)

Comment: @HighCore and this is expected because there is no difference how you will pass null value :(

Comment: @Evgeny it works in my sample application. Post your current XAML and binding source.

Comment: @Evgeny "and this is expected because there is no difference how you will pass null value": that's not true. When you bind Image.Source to a property of type string, WPF automatically performs a type conversion from `string` to `ImageSource` by a built-in TypeConverter. This conversion is bypassed when you apply the DataTrigger as shown in this answer. You may however apply your own [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) for the type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try `FallBackValue` attribute which sets a value when binding exception is thrown ([msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx))
eg: `FallbackValue="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/nocover.png"` or `{x:null}`

There is also  `TargetNullValue` which sets a default value when the bound data is null

Another option would be trying with a converter which returns a default value if parameter is null..

Resolved similar issue  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530957/handling-null-when-binding-to-an-image-in-xaml)