# WPF Error - Where to look for source / solution

Tags: c#, wpf

I am very new to WPF.  I create an app that gets data from a web service.  Data consists of strings, dates, numbers and images.

The app runs (no crashing) however and I thought all is fine.  My data is also displayed just fine.  However, I see in the Output window following:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: ImageSourceConverter cannot convert from (null).
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
   at System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
```

What could cause this error?  Where to start looking to fix this issue?

Sorry, I know the question is bit vague and I have not provided code because dont know what to provide, it would be to much to provide it all.

Comment: Did you debug and check at which point the error and coming?

Comment: Check the code where you are trying to show Image. ImageSource should be non-null.

Comment: Can you share the part of the XAML which has the <Image> tag with it's *Source* property being bound?

Comment: just have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997365/solution-to-binding-errors-thrown-by-setting-image-source-to-a-binding-to-null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the data in the first line of the error message:

> Cannot convert `<null>` from type `<null>` to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'

This means that in your XAML somewhere you're binding a property that expects to receive an ImageSource - usually, this means an `<Image Source="{Binding ...}"/>`. However, instead of an instance of an ImageSource, you're giving it `null`.

You might not notice it in the visual layout because it just *doesn't appear*, but you should go over your image bindings and look for it.